# Splitting WavPack files when the .cue file and .wv file have different names?

Tags: audio, conversion, flac

If a directory contains an album encoded as one large .wv file and a .cue file, splitting the entire album into individual .flac tracks is a simple task:

`$ cuebreakpoints foo.cue | shnsplit -o flac foo.wv`

What I'd like to know is how to split a file where the names don't match up, e.g.: 'foobar.wv' and 'foo.cue'. If I attempt this I get this error message:

```
shnsplit: warning: none of the builtin format modules handle input file: [foobar.wv]
shnsplit: error: cannot continue due to error(s) shown above
```

Do I need to alter the .cue file? Because simply renaming 'foobar.wv' to 'foo.wv' prior to splitting doesn't seem to work for me. Or is there something wrong with the `wavpack` package?

PS: I didn't know how to tag this question properly. Sorry 'bout that.

**Some more info**

To be clear, I should point out that the text inside the .cue files points to the appropriate .wv files.

**Yet more info**

I'm having a bit of luck, for whatever reason, by decompressing the .wv to .wav and then altering the .cue file accordingly.

Not ideal but it's working so far.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `FILE` line in the cue file points to the correct name. In your case it should read:

```
FILE "foobar.wv" WAVE
```

Then renaming `foo.cue` to `foobar.cue` should do the trick.

Another option is to recreate the cue sheet from the original wv file (provided the info is there):

```
$ wvunpack -c foobar.wv > foobar.cue
```

then split as usual.

Answer (score 1):

The `.cue` file has a section within it, `FILE` that points to the wavpack file, `.wv`:

```
$ grep FILE cdimage.wv.cue
FILE "cdimage.wv" WAVE
```

Incidentally, you can do all this directly with just `shnsplit`. This CLI is part of the package `shntools` on Debian/Ubuntu.

```
$ shnsplit -f cdimage.wv.cue -o flac -t '%n - %p - %t' cdimage.wv
```

This will produce files with the track number (`%n`), artist's name (`%p`), & track name (`%t`).

From `man shnsplit`:

```
      -t fmt Name  output files in user‐specified format based on CUE 
         sheet fields.  The following format‐ting strings are recognized:

              %p     Performer
              %a     Album
              %t     Track title
              %n     Track number
```

#### References

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUE_Splitting

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have wavpack installed.  So try installing that first, then go:

```
$ cuebreakpoints foo.cue | shnsplit -o flac foo.wv
```